# Typo3 (8.7.31) File is missing

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I just deployed a setup to a new server and typo3 suddenly can't find files anymore that are present in the file admin. For example I have some textpic that show me that warning.

I can access the files directly via the browser, but the file admin is marking them as missing too. I cleared the caches several times.

Do you have any idea what I could do to restore those file references?

Comment: Sounds like FAL has different information. There's a Scheduler Task "File Abstraction Layer: Update storage index". Run it once.

Comment: Indeed, it is slowly (running for 2 hours now) fixing it :)

Comment: Is the original file missing or just the processed ones? often the references to the processed files does not match the temporary files and a cleanup in the InstallTool will generate clean new processed files.

Comment: Actually all files - not just processed ones are missing. But the Update fixes it - even though it is still running :D